# Google Drive API Not Found error, only when fetching metadata

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to fetch the metadata from a Google Drive file using the `googleapis` npm package:

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  'service-user@project-title.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
  null,
  '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXX==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'], 
)

export default async ( req, res ) => {
  try {
    const drive = google.drive( { version: 'v3', auth } )
    const data = await drive.files.get( { fileId: 'XXXX' } )
    res.json( { data } )
  }
  catch ( err ) {
    console.error( err )
    res.status( 500 ).json( { error: err.message, err } )
  }
}
```

When I make the request, I'm getting a `File not found: XXXX` error. But the file does exist, and the service account I'm using has access. I can confirm that because, if I make the exact same request while adding the `alt: "media"` param:

```
const data = await drive.files.get( { fileId: 'XXXX', alt: "media" } )
```

The request works, and I'm able to get the file data. This leads me to believe the permissions are fine.

Any ideas how I can successfully fetch the file metadata (in particular - the file name)?

Comment: do a file.list if its not found then you dont have access to it.   Why are you loading auth like that?

Comment: @DaImTo your comment helped me find the issue, I needed to also include `supportsAllDrives: true` as the file was shared and not in the account's My Drive.

Comment: @DaImTo loading auth like what? Is there a better way with service accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that because the file was shared with the service account, rather than in the service account's own drive. I needed to include the param `supportsAllDrives: true`.

```
const data = await drive.files.get( { fileId, supportsAllDrives: true } )
```